# How can I open a ascx file when a ImagemButton is clicked on a Radlistview?

Tags: listview, telerik, radlistview

I have a RadListView with a set of pictures related to the company logo. I want to click on the image and open a .ascx control already created, with the details of each of the companies.

How do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to load all your user controls when the page loads, and then hide/show with JavaScript?  If so, load each of the controls in a div with a unique class that you assign in code behind (maybe the name of the control itself).  Then, in the OnItemDataBound event of your RadListView, find the image control and assign the click event with the control you want to show.  Some pseudo-code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showControl('MyUserControl')"><img src="blah" /></a>

<div class="ControlWrapper MyUserControl">
    //user control loaded here
</div>

function showControl(name){
    $("ControlWrapper").hide();
    $("." + name).show();
}
```